# SonarQube replying with NO_MIGRATION although db migration is required

Tags: sonarqube, ansible, database-migration, sonarqube5.6

We have automated the SonarQube server installation using Ansible. As part of this procedure, Ansible polls the URL `sonar/api/server/index` to check whether the server is up-and-running. As soon as an HTTP 200 is returned and the server status is equal to `SETUP`...

```
<server>
    <id>20170131094026</id>
    <version>5.6.2</version>
    <status>SETUP</status>
</server>
```

... the script triggers a database upgrade by sending a `POST` to `sonar/api/server/setup` and waiting for `MIGRATION_SUCCEEDED` to be returned.

This has worked well until now that I tried to upgrade SonarQube from version 5.6.2 to 5.6.5. For some reason `sonar/api/server/index` now always returns the status `UP` (even though the GUI clearly indicates that it's still under maintenance) and a `POST` to `sonar/api/server/setup` indicates that the database is up-to-date and no migration is needed (`NO_MIGRATION`).

However, the server is still in maintenance mode and the nexus.log keeps repeating the same line:

```
09:41:05 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
09:41:39 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
09:43:13 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
09:47:28 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
```

When I manually navigate to `sonar/setup` and click on the Update button, then a database migration starts... Has there been any changes in the API? Am I calling the wrong REST endpoints?

Comment: Could you send the full logs please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using internal web services (api/server/index and api/server/upgrade). Responses and behavior can change between versions without any notification.

You should use instead :

1. GET api/system/db_migration_status : to get the database migration status
2. POST api/system/migrate_db : to execute the migration

I encourage you to go to http:///web_api to see documentation of available web services for the version of SonarQube your using.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, now my code works again! May I ask the reason for exposing those 'at your own risk' internal API methods at all?

Comment: The reason for having internal web services is because the UI is only using web services.